# how to find index above threshold of each row

Tags: python, numpy

I have numpy array in below format:

```
array([list([0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.28552457]),
       list([0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.69565217, 0.69565217]),
       list([0.95626478, 0.95626478, 0.95513577, 0.95513577, 0.95513577]),
       ...,
       list([0.14285714, 0.14285714, 0.14285714, 0.14285714, 0.13793103]),
       list([0.73846154, 0.73846154, 0.73846154, 0.71641791, 0.71641791]),
       list([0.72727273, 0.72727273, 0.72727273, 0.70588235, 0.70588235])],
      dtype=object)
```

How can i use

```
 np.argwhere(y>0.5)
```

for the above numpy array.

I am getting error while using np.argwhere

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last) Input In [132], in <cell line: 1>() ----> 1 z=np.argwhere(y>0.5)  TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? you have your array (which you store as y) and then `np.argwhere(y>0.5)` gives you all indices you are searching for.

Comment: I need to find indice of each with threshold of 0.5.But the array contain list.

Comment: see my answer, the lists get converted into arrays automatically when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

Generating a numpy array using the following code

```py
y = np.random.random(50).reshape(10, 5)
```

should give you something like

```bash
array([[0.0992988 , 0.62179431, 0.26247934, 0.84402507, 0.05931778],
       [0.41603546, 0.6375162 , 0.66391551, 0.10959321, 0.71086281],
       [0.94060165, 0.84174581, 0.68389615, 0.20276522, 0.88082071],
       [0.04820747, 0.66052068, 0.81348755, 0.67832623, 0.96918592],
       [0.02804541, 0.47816843, 0.30916056, 0.38798535, 0.52484326],
       [0.06011845, 0.51549552, 0.76312676, 0.44300283, 0.52805978],
       [0.33544995, 0.8518729 , 0.59308601, 0.04525118, 0.5162366 ],
       [0.04688691, 0.34093081, 0.07197314, 0.868233  , 0.9434406 ],
       [0.63620516, 0.63382467, 0.2054274 , 0.01997156, 0.90429261],
       [0.68956099, 0.37559233, 0.96284643, 0.32257647, 0.31922311]])
```

You can call `np.argwhere(y>0.5)` to get the index of all values that are greater than 0.5. Here is the output I got.

```bash
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 4],
       [5, 1],
       [5, 2],
       [5, 4],
       [6, 1],
       [6, 2],
       [6, 4],
       [7, 3],
       [7, 4],
       [8, 0],
       [8, 1],
       [8, 4],
       [9, 0],
       [9, 2]])
```

You can read up more on the `numpy.argwhere` [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html).

Comment: the array is already given. I do not need genrate using random.Also numpy contain list in above example

Answer (score 0):

I changed your input and made some lists shorter than the rest. Doing that, the lists don't get converted to a `np.array` as you see in my print statements on `arr`.
Use the code with `itertools.zip_longest`, then you should be good to go. The `fill_value` is your choice what fits you the best.

```
arr = np.array([list([0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.28552457]),
       list([0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.69565217, ]),
       list([0.95626478, 0.95626478, 0.95513577, 0.95513577, 0.95513577]),
       list([0.14285714, 0.14285714, 0.14285714, 0.14285714, ]),
       list([0.73846154, 0.73846154, 0.73846154, 0.71641791, 0.71641791]),
       list([0.72727273, 0.72727273, 0.72727273, 0.70588235])], dtype='object')
print(type(arr))
print(type(arr[0]))
print(arr)

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'list'>
[list([0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.28552457, 0.28552457])
 list([0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.71641791, 0.69565217])
 list([0.95626478, 0.95626478, 0.95513577, 0.95513577, 0.95513577])
 list([0.14285714, 0.14285714, 0.14285714, 0.14285714])
 list([0.73846154, 0.73846154, 0.73846154, 0.71641791, 0.71641791])
 list([0.72727273, 0.72727273, 0.72727273, 0.70588235])]

converted_arr = np.array(list(itertools.zip_longest(*arr, fillvalue=-1))).T
print(type(converted_arr))
print(type(converted_arr[0]))
print(converted_arr)

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[ 0.28552457  0.28552457  0.28552457  0.28552457  0.28552457]
 [ 0.71641791  0.71641791  0.71641791  0.69565217 -1.        ]
 [ 0.95626478  0.95626478  0.95513577  0.95513577  0.95513577]
 [ 0.14285714  0.14285714  0.14285714  0.14285714 -1.        ]
 [ 0.73846154  0.73846154  0.73846154  0.71641791  0.71641791]
 [ 0.72727273  0.72727273  0.72727273  0.70588235 -1.        ]]
```

and then as you already provided in your question:

```
np.argwhere(converted_arr>0.5)

array([[1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [4, 0],
       [4, 1],
       [4, 2],
       [4, 3],
       [4, 4],
       [5, 0],
       [5, 1],
       [5, 2],
       [5, 3],
       [5, 4]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: arr  has datatype object as per my example.Also i am getting error `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [132], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 z=np.argwhere(y>0.5)

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'` when i use np.argwhere

Comment: sorry, I don't get where you are stuck. From my point of view, it doesn't make sense but maybe I don't have all information. To get that straight. You have a numpy array which contains lists of numbers for each row of the array ? and if you wrap that data with `np.array('your data')` it doesn't convert the lists to numpy arrays?

Comment: @ rabinzel yes you are correct

Comment: that's weird. Can you provide the whole array in your question? also show how you get to the output you posted here. there must be something wrong.

Comment: The array is very big  it contain about 4.6 million rows.

Comment: In my array dtype=object. But your array is nd.array that different i see

Comment: i have an idea. if the lists have different lengths, they won't get converted. And yes, np.argwhere won't work on lists. try this: `for i,v in enumerate('your_array'):
    if(len(v)!=len(your_array[0])):
        print('f"different length at row {i=}\n{v=}')` and tell me if I'm right. Every row which hasn't same length than your first row will get printed

Comment: see my answer, I updated it, tell me if that works for you

Comment: that works but each row is of same size.Also i need argwhere for each rows

Comment: ok, I tried. I don't know what else to say. Something HAS to be, otherwise your array would automatically convert the list to arrays. and why do you come NOW with argwhere for each row? I mean, you asked a question, why is this not mentioned?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246322/discussion-between-sudojarvis-and-rabinzel).